# Setting strict password rules

Tags: ms-access, coldfusion, passwords

I am a bit confused here. I have a form and action page for handling a user login. Presently, my action page ignores the capitalization of the password. Whether you use lower case letters, or all caps, for the password, the action.cfm page logs you in, as long as the value is correct. I want it to ONLY login if the correct password case is used. How do I solve this?

**Form:**

```
<form name="login" target="_self" method="POST" action="action.cfm">
   Username: <input name="UserName" type="text"><br/>
   Password: <input name="Password" type="password"><br/>
   <input name="" type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

**action.cfm:**

```
<cfquery name="qVerify" datasource="me.mdb"> 
    SELECT  UserName, Password 
    FROM    rbs 
    WHERE   UserName = '#UserName#' 
    AND     Password = '#Password1#' 
</cfquery> 
<cfif qVerify.RecordCount> 
    <cfset session.allowin = "True"> 
    <!--- Now welcome user and redirect to "accessgranted.cfm" ---> 
    <CFLOCATION URL="successful.html"> 
<cfelse> 
    <script> 
    alert("ACCESS NOT GRANTED. CHECK YOUR LOGIN PARAMETERS."); 
    self.location="loginpage.html"; 
    </script> 
</cfif>
```

Comment: Sounds like your passwords are stored plain text in the database. These should be hashed, immediately, if not sooner.

Comment: Thanks Matt. But how do i hash passwords in access db?

Comment: Did you do a search on "ColdFusion hashing passwords"? There should be plenty of examples.

Comment: Yes, I did. I have seen couple of examples. Thank you Leigh.

Answer (score 3):

Comparisons in Access are always case-insensitive.

So a query

```
SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE foo = 'HELLO'
```

will also return records with foo = `hello` or `Hello`.

**But:** you shouldn't store passwords in plaintext anyway. Hash them, and the problem solves itself.

Comment: Also, always use [cfqueryparam](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfqueryparam.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should save the passwords without converting to lower or upper case. Then while checking password in the login page, you should compare them as the same way.

By default comparison will be done without changing lower or upper cases.

Check your server side code.

Comment: Thanks alireza. But i still dont get it. The password is not converted to lower or upper case. For example, if your login password is love, if you enter LOVE as login password, it will still log you in. How do i solve this?

Comment: <cfquery name="qVerify" datasource="me.mdb">
    SELECT             UserName, Password
    FROM                rbs
    WHERE              UserName = '#UserName#'  AND  Password = '#Password1#'
</cfquery>
<cfif qVerify.RecordCount>
    <cfset session.allowin = "True">
    <!--- Now welcome user and redirect to "accessgranted.cfm" --->
     <CFLOCATION URL="successful.html">
<cfelse>
    <script>
        alert("ACCESS NOT GRANTED. CHECK YOUR LOGIN PARAMETERS.");
        self.location="loginpage.html";
    </script>
    </cfif>

Comment: @Foxlon: Please don't post code in comments, edit your question and add it there.

Answer (score 0):

Your table collation seems to be case-insensitive.

Check the password with ColdFusion in a case-sensitive way. For example with the function compare() which is case-sensitive, whereas compareNoCase() is case-insensitive. Compare() returns 0 if the strings are equal.

Your code would look like this:

```
<cfquery name="qVerify" datasource="me.mdb"> 
    SELECT  UserName, Password 
    FROM    rbs 
    WHERE   UserName = <cfqueryparam value="#form.UserName#">
    AND     Password = <cfqueryparam value="#form.Password#">
</cfquery> 
<cfif qVerify.RecordCount and compare(qVerify.username, form.username) eq 0 and compare(qVerify.password, form.password) eq 0> 
    <cfset session.allowin = "True"> 
    <!--- Now welcome user and redirect to "accessgranted.cfm" ---> 
    <CFLOCATION URL="successful.html"> 
<cfelse> 
    <script> 
    alert("ACCESS NOT GRANTED. CHECK YOUR LOGIN PARAMETERS."); 
    self.location="loginpage.html"; 
    </script> 
</cfif>
```

Comment: While technically true, [passwords should NOT be stored in plain text](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36833/why-should-i-hash-passwords). For security reasons, they should be hashed. As [Andre points out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39350339/104223), that also has the happy side effect of making case a non-issue...

Comment: Thanks leigh. But how do i hash passwords in access db?

Comment: @maertsch, its working now. I want to learn how to hash passwords with coldfusion. Thank you.

Comment: @Foxlon - If you found a solution, please post your code as an official "answer" to help the next guy with this same question.